# Why the Airflow Execution time is not using the schedule_interval?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler, mwaa

I wanted to see the execution time 2022-03-01T20:00:01Z but I see 2022-03-01T00:00:01Z . I want the job to be kicked off at 8PM UTC.

.. Code snipet

```
 [![default_args = {
    "owner": "delta",
    "depends_on_past": False,
    "start_date": datetime(2022, 3, 1),
    "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=5),
    "max_active_runs": 1,
    # "schedule_interval": '@daily',
    "schedule_interval": '0 20 * * *',
    "catchup": False,
}][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may have a timezone issue if it's starting at midnight instead of 8pm UTC. To set the timezone, add the following to your DAG code:

```
import pendulum
local_tz = pendulum.timezone("Etc/UTC")
```

Then in your `default_args` add:

```
"start_date": datetime(2022, 3, 1, tzinfo=localtz),
```

Check this link for more information on [timezone-aware DAGs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.3/timezone.html#time-zone-aware-dags).

If this doesn't resolve the issue, it may be because you set the `start_date` to today's date, and so the job only got picked up for the first time this morning at 00:00:01. If this is the case, your issue should resolve itself tonight and tomorrow. Remember that the `start_date` can be any time in the past if you want the DAG to start immediately.